# Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:pom:2.9.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed

Tags: maven, hadoop

Im facing issues when it comes to downloading hadoop-client and hbase-client needed for my project.

I am encountering the following error.

```
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:pom:2.9.2 from/to central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.9.2/hadoop- 
client-2.9.2.pom
```

The pom.xml that i am using in the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>map-reduce1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Java Version

[image]

Please help out by pointing me in the right direction in resolving this issue.

The url is working.

[image]

Comment: Open that https address in your browser. Does it work?

Comment: Are you running on JDK 7 ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yeah I am.

Comment: Ok..you should upgrade to JDK8 at minimum..because Java 7 is too old... The other option is to temporarily activate TLSv1.2 via `-Dhttps.protocolls=TLSv1.2` ...This is only a temporarily solution. Upgrade to newer tools...

Comment: You should also upgrade the versions of your used libraries (hadoop etc. ) because the given versions is already 3 years+ old...there are newer versions available.

Comment: BTW: Don't use image https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/296328

Comment: @khmarbaise I cannot update update the version as I am trying to run in a docker container which uses java 1.7. I will give it a try.

Comment: Then use a different docker container with newer Java version... you are using old software ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I would like to but the issue is that the image was provided by the university.  I am a bit unware on how to enable TLSv1.2 on ubuntu 20.04. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've given you the command line option... which needs to be use with every call of Maven to get the download running...The university should upgrade their parts as well....because working with old software is simply a bad idea...

Comment: I believe Hadoop 2.9 requires Java 8, by the way, but that has nothing to do with your maven errors